# Beyond Compare: how to compare all files shown in "folder compare" in separate tabs?

Tags: windows, beyondcompare

Usually when I perform "folder compare" in Beyond Compare, I would like to compare content of each file in separate tabs.
If I do *right click -> open* (or double click) on a specific file, it indeed opens a new tab and compares the content of this file.

**The problem:** How can I do that for all files instead of double click each file manually?

If I select all files and then *right click -> open*, it opens tab of "TextMerge".

[image]

Selecting the files in Windows Explorer and *right click -> Compare* is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare doesn't provide a way to open all selected files in tabs from the Folder Compare.

Alternative workflow:

1. **Edit > Expand All**.
2. Double click to view the first pair of different files.
3. Use the **Search > Next Difference Files** (Control + M) and **Search > Previous Difference Files** (Shift + Control + M) to cycle through files.

The default settings only cycle through files in the current subfolder, to make it cycle through all subfolders:

1. Open **Tools > Options** (Windows, Linux) or **Beyond Compare > Preferences** (macOS).
2. Go to the **Next Difference** section.
3. Uncheck **Limit "Next Difference Files" to current folder**.

Comment: this is not what I asked for, but thanks for the tip. Note that the 'Search > Next Difference Files' in step 2 closes the tab that was opened in step 1 and doesn't cycle through the files.

Comment: Make sure Limit "Next Difference Files" to current folder is unchecked in Tools > Options and that you've used Edit > Expand All before you double click the first pair of files. If the option is checked, it only cycles through the current subfolder. Also, it only cycles through files in expanded subfolders, so if you don't Expand All it will stop at the end of the current subfolder.

Comment: Indeed when I expand all + change the settings the Ctrl+M cycles all results, Thanks

Comment: We also discussed this by email, but for anyone else that finds this thread: Running `git difftool` launches comparisons of each pair of different files one Text Compare at a time. Git doesn't provide a method to launch them all at once. The best workaround is to use `git difftool --dir-diff` to launch all the differences in the Folder Compare.